# Site aesthetics -- banner update has poor contrast

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It seems like the banner on Biology.SE was updated to be a lighter color. Unfortunately, there is now poor contrast between the site logo and the banner background:

[image: new banner]

Can this be reverted or fixed? Who controls these things?

For what it's worth, I'm browsing the site with Chrome v100.0.4896.60, and I've noticed the same problem on mobile (Safari on iOS 15.4.1).

Comment: I've noticed the same; possibly it's related to [Every site just turned blue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377950/every-site-just-turned-blue) (MSE) based on the timing, but I've tagged with [tag:status-review] in case there's a separate issue here. Clearly this is not as-intended, it seems to be some consequence of a different intended change.

Comment: What actually changed, though, was we lost the top and side coloring; the text stayed the same: https://web.archive.org/web/20220402021659/https://biology.stackexchange.com/ It seems we've also gotten some artistic bio-ish background. Don't think any of this was shared with anyone in advance.

Comment: Thanks for sleuthing, @BryanKrause

Comment: This is indeed a bug. The team is working on fixing it.

Answer (score 8):

This bug has been fixed. More details can be found on [my answer over
on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377953/395497):

> This issue has been fixed. Short version: There was an upstream change in our [Stacks library](https://stackoverflow.design/) that caused the css specificity of the default theme to be higher than the network themes. As a result, the default theme was applied to all of the components (buttons, fonts, and so on) across the network. We put in a quick (but reliable) fix on the Stack Exchange-side of things while we look into addressing the root cause in Stacks.